# Membership dates - unexpected behaviour

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

Running 4.7.29. I'm seeing some very odd behaviour with membership sign-up and renewal.

Renewals, despite happening within the grace period, are being set with a new 'member since' date, i.e. the same as the start date. As I understand it the 'member since' date should not change if the existing membership is current (i.e. has a status that is tagged as being current, e.g. New, Current, Grace).

I'm also seeing for a new member sign-up, although the contribution is marked as pending, the membership is not pending, but set to status = New. So, when, the payment arrives a few days later and the contribution changes to 'completed', the membership is then being renewed.

We're using the GoCardless payment processor (https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless) and Rich Lott has confirmed that the processor does not touch membership code at all, relying wholly on Civi's inbuilt systems to handle memberships on contribution pages set-up for that purpose.

Anyone else seeing odd behaviour with membership dates?

Comment: I've run into a similar situation. In my case, We have members who transition from student to prospect to full membership; each transition has a membership level. We imported all of the members and their memberships. The start date and expiry dates mark their transition from one level to the next and the Member Since is supposed to mark the date they joined the organization. When their current memberships renewed, the Member since date was changed to the same date that they transitioned to that particular membership level. It's not what we were looking for.

Comment: If you are using a different membership type for each level then I'm guessing that is the issue. The member since date is likely specific to the membership type. I'm looking at https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-extras as a way to improve my control over memberships. It might help in your case.

Comment: Graham, thanks for the link to Membership Extras. That may indeed be a useful tool.